# Consultar dois dias no php

Tags: php

Estou querendo pensar ne uma forma de fazer a consulta de dois dias repetidos no mês.

Os dias são 15 e 30, gostaria de fazer um IF nessas datas onde vai me retornar um valor. No caso essa consulta seria mensal e então fiz assim `$evento = date("15/m/y"); $evento1 = date("30/m/y");`
Já bati cabeça não consegui pensar ne uma forma de fazer isso.

A consulta será feita via crontab, eu preciso apenas de retornar o valor para inserir no código cron.

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi corretamente, você poderia fazer o seguinte, no codigo php coloca

```
    $evento = date("d/m/Y")
```

para pegar o data do sistema mesmo e no crontab do seu servidor coloca pra executar nos dias 15 e 30 assim:

```
   0 0 15 * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/consulta.php
   0 0 30* * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/consulta.php
```

Espero ter ajudado...

Comment: Eu não preciso do cron, eu preciso apenas fazer o IF no dia especifico.